# Elastic search multi word partial match using regex with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, elasticsearch

I want to search multi-word using elastic search and node.js.
I am using regex for that, but seems like regex works only for a single word. can anyone please help me with that.
When I am trying to search for a movie "Sholay" with the input "shol", then I am getting the expected result. But when I am trying to search "3 Idiots" movie with input as "3 idi" it is giving me the empty result.
And I checked in my elastic search DB that the movie "3 Idiots" exists.

Please help me with that.

code I am using:

```
regexp: {
         name: {
                value: query + "*",
                }
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you wanted to use regex, if you can only use line.includes(). However, below my solution using regex ...

```js
let keyWords = ["shol", "3 idi"];
let text = `Sholay
3 Idiots
abcdef`;

keyWords.forEach((x) => {
  // If the name of the movie has metacharacteres, you will need to scape...
  console.log(text.match(new RegExp(`^.*${x}.*$`, "gim")));
});
```

Comment: I have to use elastic search for this. and here you took keywords as an array but in my case I am accepting 1 word from user.